# Cache-issue changing Cakephp database settings on the fly

Tags: cakephp

I'm building a Website in Cakephp with variable databases.
I did this with the following code:

CONTROLLER:

```
$db_host = $DB_SET['Project']['db_host']; //From other database
$db_user = $DB_SET['Project']['db_user'];
$db_pass = $DB_SET['Project']['db_pass'];
$db_database = $DB_SET['Project']['db_database'];

ConnectionManager::create("client_db", array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => $db_host,
    'login' => $db_user,
    'password' => $db_pass,
    'database' => $db_database,
    'prefix' => '',
    'encoding' => 'UTF8',
    'port' => '',
));
$DB_LINE = $this->Page->findPage('3');
```

MODEL:

```
class Page extends Model {
    public $useDbConfig = 'client_db';
    function findPage($pagenr) { 
        $page = $this->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array (
                'Page.id' => $pagenr)
        ));
    return $page;
    }
}
```

Now I also need to change of tables in the database on the Fly.
I do this using(Controller):

```
$tbl_current = array('tbl_cheques', 'tbl_wishes');
$this->Modelname->useTable  = $tbl_current[$pageid]; //Getting the pageID from an url parameter.
```

Everything works fine, only if I don't wait a while before clicking another page I get this error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Page.fqlkdf' in 'field list'
```

This because Cake still have the previous table in his Cache. 
If I wait a minute and then I change the page it works fine.
Any suggestions for this problem?
Thanks in advance,

Aäron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said, the table info is cached. So you just need to remove that cache:

```
Cache::clear(false, '_cake_model_');
```

Or, you can just temporarily disable cache

```
 Configure::write('Cache.disable', false);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried this and it doesn't work. Cache::clear(false, 'Page'); //The model is Page.php, correct? (Page extends Model...)

Comment: No, use exactly what I typed and it will clear every model's cache (Cake 2.x).

Comment: Strange... it doesn't work, I try to use the code in the function of the view and the beforefilter() function. Yes Cake 2.1. and I used App::import('Cache'); to import the class...

Comment: Ok, I found the following snippet that worked for me: Configure::write('Cache.disable', false); Thanks!

Comment: I edited the question to include your answer for anyone else searching. Glad it's working!